# UIScrollView: Can't establish status quo after a zoom

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm trying to load a low-res image into a scroll view and after the first zoom replace it with a high-res image. First attempt didn't go too well. As a way for me to better understand what's going on, I'm now trying to load the high-res image and replace it with the same high-res image after the first zoom, i.e. establish status quo. In my viewDidLoad I have:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LargeImage.png"]];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];

scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.25;
scrollView.zoomScale = 0.251497;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

This gives:
imageView.frame.size = 420,580 (frame of the scroll view)
imageView.bounds.size = 1670,2306

In scrollViewDidEndZooming: I do:

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
[imageView release];
scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;

CGRect svb = CGRectZero;
svb.size = scrollView.frame.size;
scrollView.bounds = svb;

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LargeImage.png"]];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];

scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.25;
scrollView.zoomScale = 0.251497;
```

This gives:

```
imageView.frame.size = 1670,2306  
imageView.bounds.size = 1670,2306
```

I can't figure out why imageView.frame isn't scaled as it is in viewDidLoad. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong or is missing?

Comment: Where do you put the log statements?

Comment: I've had NSLog statements "all over", but NSLog'ing the imageView right after setting the zoomScale to 0.251497 produces the two different imageView.frame values.

Answer (score -1):

You have to tell to scrollview which view you want zoomed, this is done via delegate method `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView`

So in your case add this and it's going to work!

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

Also never do:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LargeImage.png"]];
```

if you want to change instance variable always do:

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LargeImage.png"]];
```

will lead to leak..

better practice:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LargeImage.png"]];
    self.imageView = imgView;
    [imgView release];
imgView = nil;
```

If you don't do it with self your program can crash from time to time (not always which is why it is hard then to trace it)

Comment: Zooming works, the viewForZoomingInScrollView: is implemented (and the delegate set). The problem is when zooming ends and I want to do what I call "status quo", i.e. reinstate the original image. For whatever reason, the frame of imageView isn't set properly when the zoomScale is set. Whether to do self.imageView = ... or not depends on the @property definition and that isn't what I have a problem with here.

Comment: Why are you adding your imageView as subview of scrollview first in viewDidLoad and then add it as subview again in the zoom delegate. Why wouldn't you try just replacing the image in the zoom delegate with self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LargeImage.png"];

Comment: As mentioned I'm mainly doing this as an exercise to hopefully better understand how things work. imageNamed: caches images, so setting imageView.image to the same object is a no-op (have tried it).

Comment: Is this what you would like to do? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8UtGtC8Kwc (replacing an image with hi res image after zoom)

Comment: Yes, that is what I eventually want to do. Apple's PhotoScroller sample app shows how to do it using CATiledLayer in a general fashion. I'm trying to use one low-res image and replace that with a high-res image, but at least as an exercise without using CATiledLayer.